# Extract a value of a subscribe

Tags: angular

In my method I need to return "this.profile". But I can't use this.profile outside my profileObservable

```
  profileObservable: Observable<ProfileModel>;
  profile: ProfileModel;

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<ProfileModel> {
      this.store$.dispatch(new ProfileFeatureStoreActions.GetProfile());

      this.profileObservable = this.store$.pipe(
        select(
          ProfileFeatureStoreSelectors.selectProfile
        ),
        filter(profile => !!profile)
      );

      this.profileObservable.subscribe(profile => {
        this.profile = profile;
        console.log(this.profile) // here is defined

      });

      return this.profile; //it's undefined

  }
```

If you have the solution thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method inside your class like this :

```
get myProfile() {
     return this.profile;
  }
```

your profile value can now be accessed by calling the method "myProfile()".

another option would be to leverage the angular behaviour subject which you can subscribe to so as to get the last emitted value like:

step 1. register your behaviour subject just after your class properties as shown :

```
profileSubject: BehaviorSubject<ProfileModel> = new BehaviorSubject();
profile$: Observable< ProfileModel > = this.profileSubject.asObservable();
```

step2. use the registered subject to emit your profile value :

```
this.profileObservable.subscribe(profile => {
   this.profileSubject.next(profile)
});
```

to access your profile value outside your subscription do like this

```
  this.profile$.subscribe(res => {
    // the res contains your body;
   });
```

Comment: We already have observable value. We do not have to pack it. Just return `this.profileObservable`.

Comment: @kamil :by doing this (return this.profileObservable) you are returning the whole observable and not the value published.                                              
Observables are declarative—that is, you define a function for publishing values, but it is not executed until a consumer subscribes to it. The subscribed consumer then receives notifications until the function completes, or until they unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return subscribe. Your resolve return Observable so you must return Observable value.

For example:

```
return this.profileObservable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `return this.profileObservable;` then you can subscribe to it.
and another thing is why do you need this `return this.profile; //it's undefined` you can access this.profile anywhere in component as it's global variable.

Comment: I wrote the same answer below.